# AngularJs & Bootstrap3: Form validation & required field

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using angularjs 1.3 and Bootstrap 3 here.

I am trying to validate my form for required field. I added html5 "required" attribute. I also added ng-class to highlight the error but the issue is when the form loads my input field ie texbox is already highlighted. What I am looking for is to hightlight the texbox on button click. Do I have to manually check for this and show error?

I use the below code:

```
  <div class="m-grid-col-lg-10" 
       ng-class="{ 'has-error': nameForm.userName.$invalid }">
      <input type="text" name="userName" required ng-model="userName"
             class="form-control input-lg input-small" />
  </div>
```

Button click:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
        ng-click="done(nameForm.$valid)">
    Done
</button>
```

JSController code:

```
 $scope.done = function (isValid) {
        if (isValid) {
            $modalInstance.close();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/a0cLtnpr/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'has-error': nameForm.userName.$invalid && nameForm.userName.$touched
```

This way the has-error only hapepns if invalid and touched, you can also do or form.$submitted if you want to trigger on submit incase they didn't even touch it.

Updated:

```
'has-error': nameForm.userName.$invalid && (nameForm.userName.$touched || nameForm.$submitted)
```

Comment: I added $touched above. Now I dont see my input highlighted on pageload but also I dont see it highlighted when I click on the submit button. Any way to trigger on page submit. I am already returning false so I thought that might trigger. Another thing is that this works when i click on my textbox and then click outside, I can see the required field error.

Comment: nothing happens when I click the button. Its only when I click inside the textbox, validation triggers. See updated jsfiddle with your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/a0cLtnpr/10/

Comment: set the button to type="submit"  and set ng-submit="done(newForm)" (on form element) and generally I prefer to pass form into the function and check if form.$valid inside of it. But thats a preference. If you dont use ng-submit and type=submit angular doesn't know its been submit by a button click

you can cheat, and say newForm.$setSubmitted(); then call done()

Comment: Thanks adding type="submit" with ng-submit works for me.

Comment: Sorry I spoke too soon, when the form is invalid and I press submit i can now see required field error on the textbox. But when I type something in my textbox and press submit, nothing happens. I does not hits my controller. Can you edit my jsfiddle with your answer.

Comment: You're not injecting data into the modal and youre not reading data coming out of the modal. Look at the documentation on how to read resolve data and return data on modal close.
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal

Comment: Sorry Axr I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am also resolving my model in my controller. In my modal I just need to check for the required fields, I am not making use of any model there.

Comment: as per your question validations is complete. The field is correctly validated and errors are showing. 
"But when I type something in my textbox and press submit, nothing happens. I does not hits my controller. " This is where you need to figure out how to send data to controller, by looking into modal resolve and sending data back from modal to controller as per above link.

Comment: Axr, I believe I am passing data from my modal to the controller correctly as I can get the value of the modal textbox back to my controller. Anyways will look at that again. So I got this working by adding ng-submit="done(nameForm.$valid) to the form element itself. Now I can correctly validate and can submit the form. If I add same ng-submit to the button itself with the button type as submit the controller code containing the function does not gets called. Not sure what the difference it made.

Comment: Ng-submit only for form element. If you use button on click to call a function you need to mark the form as form.$setSubmitted() to trigger validation error to appear.